# Moving to another SwiftUI file screen but .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image: these are the two separate swiftuis under the same file]

I have a struct named `fridge()` in the fridge file, and I made a button in `ContentView` where if you click on it, it calls `fridge()`. However, even though I did this

```
struct fridge: View{
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            Color(UIColor(red: 0.996, green: 0.969, blue: 0.949, alpha: 1.0))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the button in the preview, I get this:

[image: open space on top]

I want it to completely go to the other screen since I'm going to add a back button. What am I doing wrong here? For reference, this is the part where I added the button:

```
VStack{
    HStack{
        Button(action: {fridgetapped = true}, label: {
           Image("add to your collection").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 160, height: 160)
                            .padding(.top,400)
                            .padding(.leading, 160)
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $fridgetapped) {
                        fridge()
                    }
                }
            }
```

I also have a problem where the buttons I click on executes another button but not the one/image assigned to it, which is also bizarre.

I tried making further pages and clicking it but it just layers on top of one another instead of actually going to the other page. Here is how it is right now:

[image: pages on top after clicking button instead of entirely going to other page]

Comment: You either need to use a [fullScreenCover](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-full-screen-modal-view-using-fullscreencover) instead of a sheet or use a [NavigationLink](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/displaying-a-detail-screen-with-navigationlink) instead.